# Microsoft Graph API - Error 400 Bad Request when trying to get an access token from code

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

Im trying to aquire an access token by following this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

the first request works just fine, but the second request fails with 400 - Bad Request:

net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)

any ideas?

my code currently looks like this:

```
const getMicrosoftToken = async () => {
  if (window.location.href === 'http://localhost:8080/') { location.assign(`http://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.VUE_APP_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=${process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=${process.env.VUE_APP_REDIRECT_URI}&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20chat.readwrite&state=12345`);
  } else {
    const code = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('code');
    const result = await fetch(`http://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.VUE_APP_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token?client_id=${process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENT_ID}&scope=chatmessage.send%20chat.readwrite&code=${code}&redirect_uri=${process.env.VUE_APP_REDIRECT_URI}&grant_type=authorization_code`, {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors'
    });
    console.log(result);
  }
};
```

im redirecting myself to the authorize request, then i get redirected back to my page with the code parameter,

and finally im trying to make a post request using the code in order to get the token.

Comment: What do you mean that second request fails? Could add more details what exactly is your first request and what is the second request that fails?

Comment: @user2250152
as a said, i am following a guide.
the first request is this: 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id&response_type&redirect_uri&response_mode&scope&state
this one redirects me to my page with the "code" url parameter.
the 2nd request is: 
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
client_id=
&scope=user.read%20mail.read
&code=
&redirect_uri=
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret=jXoM3iz

which leads to an error.

Comment: Could you please help us with complete error message?

Comment: The snippet you posted doesn't contain client_secret parameter which is required for auth code flow